# ¿Es posible actualizar los parámetros de una API desde un objeto de POWER BI?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

En un informe obtengo un conjunto de datos de una API. En función de un parámetro de esa API me devuelve un contenido u otro. Me gustaría poder modificar ese contenido en función de la selección que haga en un elemento visual del informe que va de 1 a 10, es decir, si hago click en el número 5, por ejemplo, debería llamar a la API pasándole como parámetro ese número 5 y actualizando la vista de una tabla con la nueva información. ¿Es posible hacer eso? Si en vez de una API es una BBDD de Sql Server, Power BI permite enlazar un objeto visual con un parámetro de Power Query, pero en caso de una API no lo permite. No sé si alguien tuvo este problema y encontró una solución. He revisado internet, pero no he encontrado nada que me pueda ayudar, ni siquiera orientar. Gracias.